# How to convert image with .png format to .jpg format in javascript Filereader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I have developed web application,I am using File reader for pick the image,In that i have to convert the image .png format to .jpeg format.Please help me anyone to complete the task. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please Post your code here.. a fiddle link is better.

Answer (score 10):

This is definitely possible through HTML5 canvas element. Just draw the image in a canvas. (Make the canvas element hidden if you want). Then use `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");` to get the Base64 notation of image in the required format.

Check out : 
http://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image